# How to permanently evaluate variables and execute a function when it acomplish a condition with javscript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular11

I bring an array of meetings from the server. The array contains objects of the meetings that contains the meeting start datetime and the meeting end datetime. I show all the items of the array in the template with the ngx moment pipes which shows the time remaining for the meeting to start. What I want to do is that when the meeting start time arrives a button will be shown to be able to join the meeting. Maybe there is some way to compare the current date and the meeting start date in a permanent way so that when the meeting arrives I can automatically execute a function to show the button, without needing to reload the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an observable that is has a value of true or false depending on whether the join button should be shown.

```
private getShowButtonObservable(m: Meeting): Observable<boolean> {
  const now = new Date();
  if (m.endDate.valueOf() < now.valueOf()) {
    // Meeting has ended, button will never show
    return of(false);
  } else if (m.startDate.valueOf() <= now.valueOf()) {
    // Meeting has started and is in progress
    // show button then hide it at endDate
    return timer(m.endDate).pipe(
      map(() => false), // When timer expires hide the button
      startWith(true) // Start with button shown
    );
  } else {
    // Meeting has not started
    const endTimer$ = timer(m.endDate).pipe(map(() => false));
    const startTimer$ = timer(m.startDate).pipe(map(() => true));
    return concat(startTimer$, endTimer$).pipe(startWith(false));
  }
}
```

Then you can use an async pipe to show/hide the button in HTML. For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let meeting of meetings; let index = index">
  <h2> Meeting #{{ index + 1}} </h2>
   <strong>Start date:</strong> {{ meeting.startDate }}<br />
   <strong>End date: </strong> {{ meeting.endDate }}<br />
   <button *ngIf="meeting.showJoinButton$ | async">Join</button>
</div>
```

Checkout full working example at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guzwxa).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot man, I need to learn more about observables, it's just amazing!